# UPDATE fails - SELECT denied

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql grants problem I can't work out.

```
mysql>  UPDATE frontier_remote.trident_update SET completed=NOW() WHERE mac_address="00:1b:24:a0:da:e9" AND completed IS NULL;
ERROR 1143 (42000): SELECT command denied to user 'trident_client'@'host-78-147-8-82.as13285.net' for column 'mac_address' in table 'trident_update'
mysql> SELECT mac_address from trident_update WHERE mac_address="00:1b:24:a0:da:e9" and completed is NULL;
+-------------------+
| mac_address       |
+-------------------+
| 00:0:de:ad:be:ef |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.04 sec)
```

So the update claims to fail in the select, but the select part of the command seems to work on its own.

The relevant entries in the grants table look like this:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'trident_client'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'shadow_password'
GRANT INSERT, UPDATE ON `frontier_remote`.* TO 'trident_client'@'%'
GRANT SELECT ON `frontier_test`.`trident_update` TO 'trident_client'@'%'
```

Any ideas what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Execute the following command:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES
```

> Reloads the privileges from the grant tables in the mysql database. On
>   Unix, this also occurs if the server receives a SIGHUP signal.
>
> The server caches information in memory as a result of GRANT, CREATE
>   USER, CREATE SERVER, and INSTALL PLUGIN statements. This memory is not
>   released by the corresponding REVOKE, DROP USER, DROP SERVER, and
>   UNINSTALL PLUGIN statements, so for a server that executes many
>   instances of the statements that cause caching, there will be an
>   increase in memory use. This cached memory can be freed with FLUSH
>   PRIVILEGES.

Documentation: [FLUSH](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/flush.html)